# Can't get image and text to be on the same line

Tags: html, css

I want both the "PaperKlip" text and the image to be on the same line. I tried having them both use `display: inline;` but this doesn't seem to be working. I want them to be aligned on the right side of the screen with the image all the way to the right, and the text directly to the left of it.

Instead, this is how they're showing up, one on top of the other:

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">PaperKlip</a>
<img src="images/paperklip.jpg" height="70px" width="70px" class="img-responsive" id="navbar-brand-logo" alt=""/>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-brand {
    display: inline;
    color: #FFF !important;
    text-transform: none;
    margin: 0px;
    font-size: 37px;
    padding: 20px 0px 0px;
    font-family: Roboto-thin;
    font-weight: 400;
}

#navbar-brand-logo{
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Already the images are text are inline. With your given level of information, answer if we can help you or not?

Comment: What is the error? Do you mean aligned vertically to the top? To the bottom? To the middle?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Sorry about that, I added a screenshot to show what I meant.

Comment: Try using `float: right;` on both the link and the image.

Comment: Try `display:inline-block;` and tell me what happens. That might fix your problem. Or you could do a float, but I recommend doing inline-block.

Comment: when I use your html and css,image and text are inline, I think there is something else in your css that cause your text to be on top of the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply add `float:right` to your HTML tags and reverse the ordering in your HTML, and everything is what you want. Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ekeIaxuzM4wwaowCOe9J?p=preview)
but I think there is something else in your CSS that affect these HTMLs, because I did not have text on top of image when I applied your codes.

HTML:

```
<img src="images/paperklip.jpg" height="70px" width="70px" class="img-responsive" id="navbar-brand-logo" alt=""/>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html">PaperKlip</a>
```

and here is CSS:

```css
.navbar-brand {
  display: inline;
  color: black;
  text-transform: none;
  margin: 0px;
  font-size: 37px;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px;
  font-family: Roboto-thin;
  font-weight: 400;
  float: right;
}

#navbar-brand-logo{
  display: inline;
  float: right;
}
```